# Windows 7 stopped waking up from sleep all of a sudden

Tags: windows-7, windows, sleep, wake-up

I have been using Windows 7 64 bit for a few months now.
My niece has been visiting and playing on the computer. Yesterday, when i pressed my keyboard button, it did not wake up from sleep. It required a reboot. I asked my niece if she did anything but she was clueless.

Here is the info.
When my computer goes to sleep, my monitor has nothing on it. The blue power light on my tower blinks and there is no noise from my tower. I've noticed that since yesterday, I can hear the fan still running (not sure if its power, CPU, Graphic card or hard drive).

These are the following things i've done/checked.

- Power options, checked if my keyboard is enabled to wake up the computer. It is
- Went to cmd and did powercfg -devicequery wake_armed
- Turned off hybrid sleep
- Checked my power saver settings
- Updated my Windows

None of it worked. I'm unsure about what could have suddenly caused this issue. I never did a system restore to 2 days ago and that did not help. Nothing new was installed

Comment: Check your BIOS settings, and ensure that all options related to advanced power savings are enabled.  Some of these options regulate which power states the computer is allowed to go into.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a reason why this setting would suddenly change on its own? I'm quite sure my niece is too young to even know how to accidentally access the BIOS settings.

Comment: there is no reason for the setting to change on it's own, but it's worth double checking just to maintain your own sanity ;)